# Filtering data for d3 with angular filter

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-filter

I need to display some data on a graph and in a table. I use separate directives to display both with d3.

I came across a weird problem trying to filter the data using angular's $filter. It filters the data correctly and the filtered data object logged to console from `.data()` and `.text()` and viewed with Batarang shows correct list of filtered data. So this data:

```
['abc', 'dfd', 'rer', 'abcd', 'arbr', 'ttt']
```

filtered by 'a', results in:

```
['abc', 'abcd', 'arbr']
```

The problem is that, when I display it in a table, I get:

```
abc
dfd
rer
```

It seems like d3 sees correct number of items in the array, but is uses the original list of items from that array to display the data. Has anyone encountered such a behavior previously? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you inserting/removing the elements from your d3 data array or just reassigning the entire array? if the latest, try to perform data manipulation on the array, so he can identify that is in fact the same array and some data was removed/inserted. if in fact you are manipulating the data array  and make sure you have a .exit rule for removing the corresponding nodes

Comment: It could also be that you are only using the `.enter()` selection for the updates and keying the data based on index, the default, say, `.data(dataset)`. If that is the case, you want to key it based on the values, which are changing, say, `.data(dataset,function(d) { return d; });`. However, best of all you would apply the enter/update/exit pattern, **assuming the scenario above is true**.